# GUI not appearing with eclipse JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm currently stuck with JavaFX on eclipse.

My program runs, compiles, and the java application will open as if the program is being executed correctly, however the actual GUI and app won't appear.

The main difference between my problem and the problem of many other people is:
I have the stage.show(); method being called and
the program works as intended on textEdit (Implying that this problem is due to eclipse)

In case you need it, here is the program

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) 
    {
         String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
         String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
         Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
         Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);
         stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.show();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         launch();
     }
}
```

Any ideas? I am thoroughly lost.

P.S. I am extremely new to programming - Java is my only language as of right now and this is my first time on stack overflow, so expect a dumb mistake to have been made

Comment: Code is not the problem. I run it and it works. I got some problem understanding your description, namely `method being called and the program works as intended`. Please edit to express your thoughts more clearly.

Comment: Try the following: Right-click on your source file, choose "Run As..." and "Run Configurations". Make sure it is configuring the correct application, and then choose the "Arguments" tab. Make sure the "`-XstartOnFirstThread` argument when launching with SWT" is **unchecked**. For reasons I can't figure out, this sometimes gets checked by default.